# Angular 2 Tutorial (Tour of Heroes): Cannot install npm for the tutorial at AngularJS' documentation

Tags: node.js

I am trying to learn AngulaJS 2 reading the documentation. The Hero Editor page at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html shows the directory tree. But I cannot have as it tells.

I have created a directory `angular-tour-of-heroes` and entered it using the command prompt. Then I ran the command `npm install` but it displays error and I cannot get the desired directory tree as told in the documentation.

[image]

About the system:

- Windows 10 x64
- Laragon 2.1.0 (nginx)
- node v6.6.0

Comment: Did you clone or download the QuickStart seed into your folder as it says to in the setup instructions?

Comment: @MattM Yes. should I  continue inside QuickStart or copy required files/folders into angular-tour-of-heroes?

Comment: Make sure you're inside whatever directory contains the package.json file when you run the npm install command. The warning is telling you it can't find that file.

Comment: @MattM do you mean I should clone the quickstart repository into hero directory and make changes on the current code?

Comment: Yes, follow the instructions here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html